# Add equation to OpenXML Wordprocessing document and display in Professional format

Tags: c#, openxml

I am using OpenXML to create a Word processing document and add equations. I can add the equations and these appear in the document correctly when I open in MS Word, but they are displayed in linear format rather than professional format. It is simple enough to change the display to 'professional' from within Word, but I'd rather have the equations displayed properly from the start. Is it possible to control this programmatically through Open XML? My test code is below.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sourceFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\test\equationTemplate.dotx";
            string destinationFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\test3.docx";
            // Create a copy of the template file and open the copy
            File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
            using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true))
            {
                document.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
                DocumentSettingsPart documentSettingPart1 = mainPart.DocumentSettingsPart;
                AttachedTemplate attachedTemplate1 = new AttachedTemplate() { Id = "relationId1" };
                documentSettingPart1.Settings.Append(attachedTemplate1);
                documentSettingPart1.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate", new Uri(sourceFile, UriKind.Absolute), "relationId1");
                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                var para2 = para.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.Paragraph());
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.OfficeMath myMath = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.OfficeMath(new Run(new Text(@"M=\frac{wl^2}{8}")));
                para2.AppendChild(myMath);
                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've used the OpenXML Productivity Tool to compare Word documents with linear and professional formatting and the difference is shown below. I think I need the equivalent of the OMath.BuildUp() method in Interop.Word to generate the more complex XML, but I can't find this anywhere within OpenXML.

```
 <m:oMathPara>
        <m:oMath>
         <m:r>
          <w:rPr>
           <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <m:t>
           M=\frac{wl^2}{8}
          </m:t>
         </m:r>
        </m:oMath>
       </m:oMathPara>


   <m:oMathPara>
    <m:oMath>
     <m:r>
      <w:rPr>
       <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <m:t>
       M=
      </m:t>
     </m:r>
     <m:f>
      <m:fPr>
       <m:ctrlPr>
        <w:rPr>
         <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
        </w:rPr>
       </m:ctrlPr>
      </m:fPr>
      <m:num>
       <m:r>
        <w:rPr>
         <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <m:t>
         w
        </m:t>
       </m:r>
       <m:sSup>
        <m:sSupPr>
         <m:ctrlPr>
          <w:rPr>
           <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
           <w:i/>
          </w:rPr>
         </m:ctrlPr>
        </m:sSupPr>
        <m:e>
         <m:r>
          <w:rPr>
           <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <m:t>
           l
          </m:t>
         </m:r>
        </m:e>
        <m:sup>
         <m:r>
          <w:rPr>
           <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <m:t>
           2
          </m:t>
         </m:r>
        </m:sup>
       </m:sSup>
       <m:ctrlPr>
        <w:rPr>
         <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
         <w:i/>
        </w:rPr>
       </m:ctrlPr>
      </m:num>
      <m:den>
       <m:r>
        <w:rPr>
         <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <m:t>
         8
        </m:t>
       </m:r>
       <m:ctrlPr>
        <w:rPr>
         <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
         <w:i/>
        </w:rPr>
       </m:ctrlPr>
      </m:den>
     </m:f>
    </m:oMath>
   </m:oMathPara>
```

Comment: Download Microsoft's *OpenXML Productivity Toolkit*. Make two nearly identical documents using Word that differ only in the feature you want. Use the toolkit to *diff* the two documents. Figure out what to do from there

Comment: Thanks Flydog57 - I've compared two documents and updated my question above. I think I'm looking for the equivalent of the OMath.BuiltUp() method that exists within Introp.Word.